# Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with SQL Database - Create button is not active

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I am following the tutorial for "Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with SQL Database"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase#publish-to-azure-with-sql-database

Everything is ok until the final step where the tutorial says click the "Create" button.  It's not active for me to click.

Steps to the page:
1. Right Click Project Name
2. Click Publish
3. App Service
4. Create New
5. Publish
[image]

Followed the tutorial steps and at the end Create button is not active.
[image]

I've tried logging off Microsoft account and then back in.

Create button is activated prior to clicking through the steps for adding the SQL database.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  As always, your expert help is appreciated.

EDIT:  Additional information...

I navigated before trying to publish to https://my.visualstudio.com/benefits and can see Azure block.
[image]

I have already clicked the Activate link and followed through the signup screens which came after. Received email saying

> Welcome to your new Azure subscription Sign in to the Azure portal to
>   start building your solutions.

I can also see a $50 credit in my account.
[image]

Comment: Did you activate your free Azure subscription?

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough credit to create SQL Databases. Check your subscription and the amount of money remains in subscription.

Comment: See edit above.  It looks like I have the $50 monthly credit.